# How to include relationship object in response composer-rest-server?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

We have defined `Asset` as:

```
asset PurchaseOrder identified by orderId {
  o String orderId
    --> SupplierChainParticipant createdBy
    --> SupplierChainParticipant assignedTo
  o String description    
  o String status
  o Integer quantity
  o String assetId    
}
```

and `Participant` as :

```
participant SupplierChainParticipant  identified by participantId {
  o String participantId
  o String identity
  o String type     
}
```

Now When I am fetching `Asset` details using REST API of composer-rest-server, I receive response as:

```
{
  "orderId": "o5",
  "createdBy": "resource:com.supplychain-network.SupplierChainParticipant#p1",
  "assignedTo": "resource:com.supplychain-network.SupplierChainParticipant#p2",
  "description": "New Engine",
  "status": "created",
  "quantity": 1,
  "assetId": "a1"
}
```

As currently its only returning `participantId` only while fetching `Asset` details, Is there a way to fetch details of participant along with `Asset` as JSON response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify a filter key called `include` and set the value to `resolve` then relationships will be resolved and the related assets will also be returned.

Comment: As part of request, I need to add field called "include" and value as "resolve"?

Comment: can you add an example?

Comment: 'http://localhost:3000/api/CommodityAsset?filter={"where":{"assetId":"A01"},"include":"resolve"}'

Comment: 'http://localhost:3000/api/CommodityAsset?filter={"where":{"assetId":"A01"},"include":"resolve"}'

Answer (score 1):

To improve upon the accepted answer with example -

```
1. 'http://localhost:3000/api/PurchaseOrder?filter={"where":{"orderId":"A01"},"include":"resolve"}'

2. 'http://localhost:3000/api/PurchaseOrder?filter={"include":"resolve"}'
```